# Tensorflow Debug options

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I am running a model which is consuming too much memory. Does tensorflow have an option where I can know which operations are consuming how much memory?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This looks way too abroad. Could you post some of your code or any examples?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest Tensorflow Profiler;

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/core/profiler

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/profiler/g3doc/profile_memory.md